# How can I align a checkbox and its labels with a dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an index.html with its header looking like this:
[image: click]

and I want to align the checkbox and its label with the dropdown "In ordine".

I'm only using bootstrap (no custom classes) and my page looks like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="alert alert-secondary">
                        <form action="{{ url('admin/students') }}" method="GET" id="filters" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="filters" value="on">

                            <div class="form-row table mb-0">

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="name">Nume</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nume" @if(request()->has('nume')) value="{{ request()->get('nume') }}" @endif>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="domeniu_doctorat_id">Domeniu doctorat</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="domeniu_doctorat_id">
                                        <option value=0>Selecteaza domeniu</option>
                                        @foreach($domenii as $domeniu)
                                            <option value="{{ $domeniu->id }}" @if(request()->get('domeniu_doctorat_id') == $domeniu->id) selected="selected" @endif>
                                                {{ $domeniu->nume }}
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="conducator_doctorat_id">Conducator doctorat</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="conducator_doctorat_id">
                                        <option value=0>Selecteaza conducator</option>
                                        @foreach($conducatori as $conducator)
                                            <option value="{{ $conducator->id }}" @if(request()->get('conducator_doctorat_id') == $conducator->id) selected="selected" @endif>
                                                {{ $conducator->nume }}
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="name">An inmatriculare</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="an_inmatriculare" @if(request()->has('an_inmatriculare')) value="{{ request()->get('an_inmatriculare') }}" @endif>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="name">Forma de pregatire</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="forma_admitere_id">
                                        <option value=0>Selecteaza</option>
                                        @foreach($forme as $forma)
                                            <option value="{{ $forma->id }}" @if(request()->get('forma_admitere_id') == $forma->id) selected="selected" @endif>
                                                {{ $forma->nume }}
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="name">Status</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="status">
                                        <option value="0">Selecteaza</option>
                                        <option value="1">Normal</option>
                                        <option value="2">Intrerupere</option>
                                        <option value="3">Prelungire</option>
                                        <option value="4">Gratie</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="name">Studenti pe pagina</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="paginare">
                                        <option value="20">20</option>
                                        <option value="50">50</option>
                                        <option value="100">100</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="name">Ordonare dupa</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="ordonare-dupa-camp">
                                        <option value="0">Selecteaza</option>
                                        <option value="1">Nume</option>
                                        <option value="2">An inmatriculare</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="name">In ordine</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="ordine">
                                        <option value="ASC">Ascendenta</option>
                                        <option value="DESC">Descendenta</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group form-check col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="name">Include studentii respinsi</label><br/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="respinsi" @if(request()->has('respinsi')) checked @endif>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-6 align-self-end text-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="cauta">Cauta</button>
                                    <a href="{{ url('admin/students') }}" class="btn btn-light">Anuleaza</a>

                                    <button class="btn btn-light" name="action" type="submit" value="exporta-excel">Exporta Excel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I searched for something similar in the bootstrap documentation, but I didn't find anything yet.

//edit:
This is what I wanted when I wrote the question:
[image: photo]

but because I waasn't explicit enough I had to accept that answer. I forgot to mention that I wanted that checkbox to be centered relative to the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switching Bootstrap classes for input checkbox:
Replace:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="respinsi" >
```

For:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check form-check-inline" name="respinsi" >
```

And you'll get this view:
[Form view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGDlw.png)

Comment: This was the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the checkbox over the drop down, and the label on the same vertical line as In ordine, so does this do what you need?

If not, maybe you could modify your image to show what you want.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="alert alert-secondary">
                    <form action="students" method="GET" id="filters">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filters" value="on">

                        <div class="form-row table mb-0">

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                <label for="name">Nume</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nume" @if(request()->has('nume')) value="{{ request()->get('nume') }}" @endif>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                <label for="domeniu_doctorat_id">Domeniu doctorat</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="domeniu_doctorat_id">
                                    <option value=0>Selecteaza domeniu</option>
                                    @foreach($domenii as $domeniu)
                                    <option value="{{ $domeniu->id }}" @if(request()->get('domeniu_doctorat_id') == $domeniu->id) selected="selected" @endif>
                                        {{ $domeniu->nume }}
                                    </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                <label for="conducator_doctorat_id">Conducator doctorat</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="conducator_doctorat_id">
                                    <option value=0>Selecteaza conducator</option>
                                    @foreach($conducatori as $conducator)
                                    <option value="{{ $conducator->id }}" @if(request()->get('conducator_doctorat_id') == $conducator->id) selected="selected" @endif>
                                        {{ $conducator->nume }}
                                    </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                <label for="name">An inmatriculare</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="an_inmatriculare" @if(request()->has('an_inmatriculare')) value="{{ request()->get('an_inmatriculare') }}" @endif>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                <label for="name">Forma de pregatire</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="forma_admitere_id">
                                    <option value=0>Selecteaza</option>
                                    @foreach($forme as $forma)
                                    <option value="{{ $forma->id }}" @if(request()->get('forma_admitere_id') == $forma->id) selected="selected" @endif>
                                        {{ $forma->nume }}
                                    </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                <label for="name">Status</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="status">
                                    <option value="0">Selecteaza</option>
                                    <option value="1">Normal</option>
                                    <option value="2">Intrerupere</option>
                                    <option value="3">Prelungire</option>
                                    <option value="4">Gratie</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4  col-lg-3">
                                <label for="name">Studenti pe pagina</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="paginare">
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                    <option value="50">50</option>
                                    <option value="100">100</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                <label for="name">Ordonare dupa</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="ordonare-dupa-camp">
                                    <option value="0">Selecteaza</option>
                                    <option value="1">Nume</option>
                                    <option value="2">An inmatriculare</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                <label for="name">In ordine</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="ordine">
                                    <option value="ASC">Ascendenta</option>
                                    <option value="DESC">Descendenta</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group form-check col-md-4 col-lg-3 ml-n1">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="respinsi" checked style="margin-top: 0.375rem">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="name">Include studentii respinsi</label>                                    
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-6 align-self-end text-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="cauta">Cauta</button>
                                <a href="{{ url('admin/students') }}" class="btn btn-light">Anuleaza</a>

                                <button class="btn btn-light" name="action" type="submit" value="exporta-excel">Exporta Excel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, please check my edit. My explanation was really poor. Sorry for wasting your time.